# Windows7 host Virtualbox 4.3 Ubuntu 14.04 guest not internet in guest. Neither with NAT nor with Bridge

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox

I have above mentioned constellation.

In both the versions of network settings, I get the Ips. In the bridge connection, I even get to see the network places. So I think the network connection is working.

The windows 7 host is behind a corporate firewall. Can this be the reason that I am not getting internet on the guest system ? Can I some how use the host system as internet proxy for the guest as I have internet on the host system.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, there was a automatic proxy script configured.

I configured the proxy in ubuntu and internet is working now.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer to help future people. I'm having the same trouble, but not sure how to try your solution.